# Set up a user for a program

Tags: users, useradd

`/etc/passwd` shows many "virtual" users that are essentially for programs to use, rather than for people.

How do I go about setting up such a user?

All I need is a user that isn't used for anything else and that the super user can change into.

I don't need anything else (password, home directory, etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just call [`useradd`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/useradd) and pass it the arguments you want. To create a system user, passs the `-r` option. If you don't want a home directory, pick something like `/none` and pass the `-M` option. If you want to be able to use `su` to run commands as that user, the user needs to have a valid shell.

```
useradd -r -d /none -M -U -s /bin/sh
```

I don't recommend modifying the `passwd` file manually. You risk making a syntax error or accidentally deleting something important. If you must edit `passwd`, call [`vipw`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/vipw), which protects against concurrent modification.

Answer (score 0):

Simply create the user as usual, don't give it any password. Rm -rf the /home/thatuser directory, and edit /etc/passwd to set the shell for that user to /bin/false.

You could model the /etc/passwd entry after other system users you may see in there. Just make sure you understand the /etc/passwd entry and google it if you need to.

Of course also make sure files and folders allow your new system user to do it's job.

Answer (score 0):

Simply adding an entry to `/etc/passwd` seems to do the job and work.

I guess `useradd` is more robust as it does a couple of additional things without doing needless stuff like setting up a user directory.

(It's a little weird though, that for such a small thing it needs to take 200ms and open and close /etc/passwd about 900 times as it strace shows.)